# UpdateItem with many attributes

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, insert-update

I am trying to update an item which has many attributes (more than 100). I can see there are two ways to update this item.

**PutItem**: PutItem can update the item, as per my understanding I need to send all the 100 attributes for each request because I am using struct for marshaling and unmarshaling the request data. If I skip any field default value will be inserted into table.

**UpdateItemInput**: We can update table using UpdateItemInput as follows -

```
    svc := dynamodb.New(session.New())
    input := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
    ExpressionAttributeNames: map[string]*string{
        "#AT": aws.String("AlbumTitle"),
        "#Y":  aws.String("Year"),
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        ":t": {
            S: aws.String("Louder Than Ever"),
        },
        ":y": {
            N: aws.String("2015"),
        },
    },
    Key: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue{
        "Artist": {
            S: aws.String("Acme Band"),
        },
        "SongTitle": {
            S: aws.String("Happy Day"),
        },
    },
    ReturnValues:     aws.String("ALL_NEW"),
    TableName:        aws.String("Music"),
    UpdateExpression: aws.String("SET #Y = :y, #AT = :t"),
}

result, err := svc.UpdateItem(input)
```

Here we need to write **ExpressionAttributeNames** for many attributes, and if attributes to be updated are dynamic how should I handle this.

I am not sure which is the efficient way to handle update. Please suggest which is the better way OR there is any other way to handle this situation.

Answer (score 3):

You are right that a `PutItem` **replaces** any existing item that has the same key, so if you want to only **merge** a bunch of new attribute values into an existing item, you need to use `UpdateItem`.

One option is indeed, as you said, to use the `UpdateExpression` syntax. You'll need to create a string like `SET #a1 = :a1, SET #a2 = :a2, ...` and also all set these a1 etc., but that's not such a hard programming exercise.

Another option is instead of `UpdateExpression`, use the older `AttributeUpdates` syntax, with a bunch of `PUT` operations. This is perhaps slightly easier (you only build one JSON list instead of an expression plus two lists) but both really require a bit of simple programming.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I was just trying to know Is this standard approach or we are also having something in Golang similar to DynamoDB.DocumentClient() in node js to make things little easier.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your API functionality. Because you have many attributes, PutItem requires you to include all those attributes when updating so it doesn’t get overwritten. If you want an API to overwrite the whole item per request, then PutItem is the better choice. But if you want an API to only update certain fields without overwriting the fields you don’t have on your struct, then UpdateItem is the better choice. Also, note that write capacities will differ with UpdateItem vs PutItem.

Here’s a way I found to automatically generate the Update expression for UpdateItem as it seems tedious manually doing it. Note that this is not the most efficient way to do this in regards to latency but preferred the non optimal latency to create update expression automatically.

```
import (
  "encoding/json"
  "log"


  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute"
  "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/expression"
)

type Service struct {
  db        *dynamodb.DynamoDB
  tableName string
}

func Update[T any](service *Service, keyObj interface{}, obj *T) error {
  tkey, err := dynamodbattribute.MarshalMap(keyObj)
  if err != nil {
    log.Println("Error(Update):", err)
    return err
  }

  var dict map[string]interface{}
  b, _ := json.Marshal(obj)
  json.Unmarshal(b, &dict)

  var update expression.UpdateBuilder
  for key, value := range dict {
    update = update.Set(expression.Name(key), expression.Value(value))
  }

  expr, err := expression.NewBuilder().
    WithUpdate(update).
    Build()

  input := &dynamodb.UpdateItemInput{
    ExpressionAttributeNames:  expr.Names(),
    ExpressionAttributeValues: expr.Values(),
    TableName:                 &service.tableName,
    Key:                       tkey,
    UpdateExpression:          expr.Update(),
  }

  log.Printf("%v", input)

  _, err = service.db.UpdateItem(input)
  return err
}
```